# JSONDecoder type is not appropriate. Code 3840

Tags: swift, urlsession

I'm trying to make a call to the Zomato API (Categories). I end up getting an error regarding dataCorrupted and code 3840.

I'm pretty sure I have the incorrect "type" within JSONDecoder().decode(type:, from:) or my Category struct is not set up properly.

My API call:

```
let baseURL = URL(string: "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/")
let categoryURL = baseURL?.appendingPathComponent("categories")
var request = URLRequest(url: categoryURL!)
request.addValue("myAPIKey", forHTTPHeaderField: "user-key")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: baseURL!) { (data, response, err) in
   guard let data = data else {return}

   do {
     let courses =  try JSONDecoder().decode([Categories].self, from: data)
     print(courses)
   } catch let jsonErr {
        print(jsonErr)
   }
}.resume()
```

My Struct:

```
struct Categories: Codable{
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?   
}
```

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "categories": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Delivery"
            }
        },
        {
            "categories": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Dine-out"
            }
        }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how your JSON look like ?

Comment: Just added the expected JSON to the post @Balanced

Comment: Horrible JSON structure. The inner `categories` key is completely pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your data types as below,

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let categories: [Category]
}

struct Category: Codable {
    let categories: Categories
}

struct Categories: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: baseURL!) { (data, response, err) in
   guard let data = data else {return}

   do {
     let courses =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
     print(courses)
   } catch let jsonErr {
        print(jsonErr)
   }
}.resume()
```

You can always put your `JSON` here at [app.quicktype.io](http://app.quicktype.io) to get the correct Data Types.

Comment: It still happens after trying this. I looked around and tried JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) but that didn't work either. The raw response from postman seems to come back fine though.

Comment: This did indeed work. I was using baseURL instead of request. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [[String: Categories]]].self, from: data)

print(courses["categories"]![0]["categories"]?.name)  // prints Optional("Delivery") base on your json    

let categoriesAsArray = (courses["categories"].map { $0 })?.map { $0["categories"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

as @vadian pointed out, the problem comes from your API.

This is what your API should answer for your code to work :

```
[
    {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Delivery"
    },
    {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Dine-out"
    }
]
```